# (Android) No Class Def Found Error for com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror

I've added the following (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to my /libs folder and have also put it in the module settings as a library and ticked the export button. In the actual file there are no errors given that it can't find the class and when I do import com.loopj and so-forth it completes it for me and shows me the available options.

However, when I run it on my phone it gives the following errors:

```
12-02 23:00:08.943    8209-8209/mobi.vassilev.beam E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class   'com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient', referenced from method mobi.vassilev.beam.GoogleLoginActivity.requestAPIKeyFromOAuthToken
12-02 23:00:09.183    8209-8209/mobi.vassilev.beam E/﹕ file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
12-02 23:00:10.453    8382-8382/? E/ObjectHelper﹕ Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo
12-02 23:00:10.598    8209-8209/mobi.vassilev.beam E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient
            at mobi.vassilev.beam.GoogleLoginActivity.requestAPIKeyFromOAuthToken(GoogleLoginActivity.java:118)
            at mobi.vassilev.beam.GoogleLoginActivity.access$200(GoogleLoginActivity.java:24)
            at mobi.vassilev.beam.GoogleLoginActivity$OnTokenAcquired.run(GoogleLoginActivity.java:105)
            at android.accounts.AccountManager$11.run(AccountManager.java:1335)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 23:00:10.633      513-548/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: mobi.vassilev.beam
```

and the extract of code (not complete obv as the URL is fake, but that shouldn't affect anything):

```
  private void requestAPIKeyFromOAuthToken(String token) {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();        // <-- this is line 118
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams("token", token);

        client.post("https://myrailsapp.com/api/v1/auth/verify", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.w("OAUTH", "Got API key from server: " + response);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Log.w("OAUTH", "Error getting API key");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.connection_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Would anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thank you very much,
Daniel

Comment: Which IDE what you using?

Comment: Which api level you use...

Comment: have u added the jar file into the build path?

Comment: @coelho I am using android studio.

Comment: @harshit-rathi target API is 17 and min is 11.

Comment: @Virag believe I have.. I added it to the module settings and build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, you have to add your jar into the lib folder, add the dependency into the build.gradle file and call `gradlew clean` from console. The gradlew is in your project directory.

Check this thread for more details: [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: That did it! I used Build -> Rebuild Project to emulate gradlew clean and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much

Comment: what about in Eclipse?